# Geometry Concave Question

Tags: geometry

I have a question that may be simple but I am having trouble wrapping my head around it. For the part seen in the link, the radius going up and down(north-south) is around 60'. the radius going left or right(east-west) is about 65'. These radii are consistent for the length of the part. Knowing this, are the grid squares(disregarding the triangles) the same dimensions throughout the part. As in could I take any grid square and replace any other grid square. or would each grid square have different dimensions from every other grid square.

[image]